# Work details in VSTS only count unassigned work

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem

I noticed a weird issue this morning in the `Work details` pane in `VSTS`. The amount of `Team work` doesn't match the sum of assigned and unassigned work, but only includes the unassigned work.

See the screenshot below, I'd expect to have *(74 of 82 h)* in the `Work` bar. The assigned works are all done by people of the current team, their capacity is set up properly (no person has 0 capacity but assigned work).

I wonder if there's a setting for this behaviour or I misinterpret the feature.

[image: VSTS screenshot of the workload pane]

Answer (score 0):

The work that is in the Team's sprint, but is unassigned to a specific person is considered to be assigned to the Whole team.

I understand this may be confusing.

You can consider this to be the remaining, unassigned work. The well from which you will assign the work from. Then depending on how your team works, they may pre-assign all the work as part of a planning event, or if they work in a more pull-based setup (like Scrum advises), they self-assign work from this well during the sprint.